# How to Run my Android apps on different Target?

Tags: android

How to run my android  application on different android versions. I have created one program in android. That program is running fine in android 4.2 but not in the lower versions of android.
When I run this program in the Android 2.3.3 using emulator it gives me error "Application has stopped unexpectedly".
How can I run the program in any version of android?

Comment: Start by looking at the error in logcat.  If it's still not clear, then post the logcat error stacktrace.

Comment: please check your logcat and post the error you get

Answer (score 2):

Write this into your menifest file if you are awaiting for the targets:

```
<uses-sdk
        android:minSdkVersion="8"
        android:targetSdkVersion="15" />
```

Comment: @Nilesh Wani : if you got the idea,then you can accept the answer

Answer (score 1):

To run multiple devices:

A) In AndroidManifest.xml set minimum sdk version like

uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="7"

B) if you are using some Classes that are not available in Andoid's lower version then make sure to integrate android-support-v4.jar in libs folder and set it to your build path by right click on this jar file from libs folder of your application.

If you have any problem plz reply.

Thanks!

Comment: Hello Manmeet,I did this A and B point but got problem this is three emulator i was created and i was run 1)Nexus S(4.0",480 * 800:hdpi)
2)7.0"WSVGA(Tablet)(1024 * 600: mdpi)
3)3.2"HVGA slider (ADPI)(320 * 480:mdpi) But got same problem.can You please give me answer. Thanking You

Comment: Hi Nilesh, Could you please send error log for this

Comment: I have created currencyConverter apps and this apps did runs on 2.3.3 and 4.2 version but got the error i provide console error and log error. can you please help me to find this error.

console ->
[2013-01-04 11:20:58 - CurrrencyconverterCpy] Failed to install CurrrencyconverterCpy.apk on device 'emulator-5554!
[2013-01-04 11:20:58 - CurrrencyconverterCpy] (null)
[2013-01-04 11:20:58 - CurrrencyconverterCpy] Launch canceled!

Comment: Please clean your code and run again.

Comment: Please make sure to create emulator again. Are you using any library like camera or else?

Answer (score 0):

1. You can change your the Build Target for your project at any time:

   Right-click the project in the Package Explorer, select Properties, select Android and then check the desired Project Target.
2. Edit the following elements in the AndroidManifest.xml file (it is in your project root directory)

   In this case, that will be:

   ```
   <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />
   <uses-sdk android:targetSdkVersion="17" />
   ```

   Save it
3. Rebuild your project.

   Click the Project on the menu bar, select Clean...
4. Now, run the project again.

   Right Click Project name, move on Run as, and select Android Application

By the way, reviewing [Managing Projects from Eclipse with ADT](http://developer.android.com/guide/developing/projects/projects-eclipse.html) will be helpful. Especially the part called Creating an Android Project.